# Call multiple modal popups from webform in asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to call multiple modal popups  from a same webform, but I don't want to write them all in the same aspx file, so that's why I thought about using a masterpage.

This is part of the code so far:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Trabajadores.master.cs" Inherits="Trabajadores" %>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Modal" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->


                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked small">
                    <li><a href="~/Empresas/Trabajadores/Ventanas/Empresas.aspx" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Empresas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Empresas/Trabajadores/Ventanas/Obras.aspx" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Obras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Empresas/Trabajadores/Ventanas/Haberes.aspx" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Haberes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Empresas/Trabajadores/Ventanas/Descuentos.aspx" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Descuentos</a></li>
                </ul>
```

And this is one of the modal popups:

```
<%@ Page Title="Haberes" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Trabajadores.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Haberes.aspx.cs" Inherits="Empresas_Trabajadores_Ventanas_Haberes" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Modal" runat="server">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>

</asp:Content>
```

But it's not working. However, I think if I use a masterpage it will redirect the page in order to open a modal popup, so I'm wondering if there is a way to open multiple modal popups without redirecting the page (so maybe I should not use a materpage, but a c# function instead).

Comment: MasterPages are for layout(theme/menus/navigation panes etc.) sharing. Either you write all those modal html in a page to load into the popup, based on some criteria from jQuery/javascript if they are not too many or use some asynchronous way like jQuery to call a server side service and get the modal html dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your modal popup logic should be wrapped around a parent `<div>` which has the following style rules `class="modal fade"`.

In the example below I have two different modal popups defined in the Master page, then all I have to do to call them from a child page is call`$('#modalPopupID').modal('show');`

**Master page:**

```
%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="jqgrid_example.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div id="body">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal2">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Child page:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ModalPopupExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="jqgrid_example.ModalPopupExample" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#modal1').modal('show');
        //Or uncomment the line below to show the other modal popup
        //$('#modal2').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```